# How can I access axios data globally

Tags: javascript

I would like to store the data got from Axios globally as I want to use it in multiple functions.
when I try to console within the function where I have called data() method, I'm getting the data as expected.
But when I try to console data outside the function I get it as "**undefined**", though I have defined **resp** globally outside function

Can anyone let me know how to store the data globally or within some other function?
can I get workaround to get the data outside function

```
let resp;
  const data =  () =>{
     return  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/s/api/v1/events/data?`)
    
     }

async function data1(){
 resp = await data()
}
data1()

console.log(resp)
```

expected data as below in both place

```
 {
test1233: [ 'abc', 'def' ],
  test1222: [],
  dadad: [ 'adc', 'derf' ],
test123: [ 'abc', 'def' ],
  test12: [],
  dadadaa: [ 'adc', 'derf' ],

}
```

Comment: Please read the duplicate linked above. This is all explained in excruciating detail there. What you want is simply not possible, and you'll need to accept this fact and work with it.

Comment: *"can I get workaround"* — The "workaround" is to put the code that needs the async value where it will be available; in this case inside `data1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is `async` (it returns a Promise). You have to wait for the Promise to complete, e.g.

```
data1().then(x => console.log(resp));
```

or

```
await data1();
console.log(resp);
```

(same thing you are already doing inside your function: you await the Promise of the axios call).

That said, it's almost certainly futile to populate global state by an asynchronous function, because you cannot really know when the function completes.